# Is there a way to run JBehave from with in main method like Cucumber's Main.run() method

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-jvm, jbehave, cucumber-java

I would like to initiate running of the BDD stories from with a Java's main method. Just like cucucumber's Main.run(), is there a similar way to specify JBehave configuration settings to a method and run it.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done via extension of `JUnitStory/JUnitStories` and adding `main` method:

```java
import org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStories;

public class MyStories extends JUnitStories {

    // add configuration here

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        new MyStories().run();
    }
}
```

Full example including full sample configuration can be found in the official JBehave repository: [org/jbehave/examples/executable_jar/MyStories.java](https://github.com/jbehave/jbehave-core/blob/master/examples/executable-jar/src/main/java/org/jbehave/examples/executable_jar/MyStories.java)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for not explaining properly. I meant if I could run the Stories without the help of JUnit, i.e. what is the starting point for jbehave without junit in picture. Similar to Cucumber's Main.run() that I can directly call with proper arguments

Comment: @user578219 actually JUnit is not used here, just the annotated method is used, you can copy content of `JUnitStories#run`and extend `ConfigurableEmbedder`, so that all references to JUnit will be eliminated